# Jest for react-notification

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I updated my React project to react-notifactions(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-notifications)

While writing jest cases, for alert("Login Failed"), I mocked using window.alert = jest.fn().
Now as I updated to react-notifaction like below
NotificationManager.error(Login failed!) how do I mock it

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if your Jest configuration is aware that it's testing for browsers vs Node.

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#browser-boolean